# Using Matlab interp3 without calling first to meshgrid

Tags: matlab

I have a MATLAB 3D matrix that I want to interpolate in the third dimension. I am using MATLAB interp3 to do this:

```
final_3D_mat=interp3( hor_inds_mm, vert_inds_mm, prev_depth_axis_mm,...
                      prev_3D_mat, ...
                      hor_inds_mm, vert_inds_mm, new_depth_axis_mm )
```

The sizes of the arrays that are used:

```
size(prev_3D_mat)
size(hor_inds_mm)
size(vert_inds_mm)
size(prev_depth_axis_mm)
size(new_depth_axis_mm)

ans =
   337   507    17
ans =
     1   507
ans =
     1   337
ans =
     1    17
ans =
     1   337
```

I do not want to call meshgrid before the call to interp3, and use the X,Y,Z arguments of interp3 as vectors. However I keep getting an error of :

```
??? Error using ==> interp3 at 128
XI,YI, and ZI must be the same size or vectors of different
orientations.
```

I tried to swap the places of hor_inds_mm and vert_inds_mm arguments, but got the error:

```
??? Error using ==> interp3 at 128
The lengths of X,Y and Z must match the size of V.
```

I also tried to change the orientations of the vectors like this:

```
final_3D_mat=interp3( hor_inds_mm, vert_inds_mm', permute(prev_depth_axis_mm,[1 3 2]),...
                      prev_3D_mat, ...
                      hor_inds_mm, vert_inds_mm',permute(new_depth_axis_mm,[1 3 2]));
```

But I got the same error:

```
??? Error using ==> interp3 at 128
XI,YI, and ZI must be the same size or vectors of different
orientations.
```

Can someone help please ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close to success, just need to make the orientation of first two indices different:

```
final_3D_mat=interp3( hor_inds_mm', vert_inds_mm, prev_depth_axis_mm,...
                      prev_3D_mat, ...
                      hor_inds_mm', vert_inds_mm, new_depth_axis_mm ) ;
```

Comment: Doing this I get the error:    ??? Error using ==> interp3 at 128
The lengths of X,Y and Z must match the size of V.

Comment: We defined the variable differently. I just updated the answer following your way, and it should work now.